# How to access SQL DB in Azure?

Tags: sql-server

I don't get it - after Google searching for a few hours and installing a lot of junk I still don't see the good, old SQL Management Studio anywhere.

[This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) is the big one that costs money. [This one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55994) instaled the server but not the client that I want to use to access my DB in the Azure.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm a little bit lost here...what do you want, create an sql server instance in MS Azure, or just create an Azure SQL Database and access it from your desktop?

Comment: Neither! I see how you get lost. I want to find the tool that you connect to an already created instance with. It's driving me crazy because I just can't find it! Please advise like if I'm a slow banana.

Comment: This one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: That's the one I link to in my question. It's the big one, payable. I need the Express version which is free. Also, I recall that one could download just the client, which was a tiny EXE file compared to this GB-atrocity.

Comment: Nope....if you read like the third paragraph, it say `SSMS is free!`

Comment: I was under the impression that Sql Server was payable and the Sql Server Express was free.I was mistaken, you say? Still, I'd need to download just the client. Will that install it for me? I didn't see it in the Start menu after the installation...

Comment: just install ssms and connect to the sql server db

Comment: Just for the record, that link is not for sql server...it's just to download the installer of SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @Hackerman And just to be perfectly clear - Sql Server Management Studio is only the client, not the server? Or is it including the server?!

Comment: Yep....just the client; in the early versions of SQL Server, they come together, but not now.

Comment: @Hackerman I got mislead by the size of that thing. It's huge for just a client! We're talking a couple of Gigs!

Comment: The size for the installer is 801 megs..

Comment: @Hackerman Correct. Still much bigger than I expected. At any rate, please post the summary of the comments as a reply so I can accept it.

Comment: @Hackerman Wait, actually. I just reinstalled it and guess what - I don't get the Sql Studio at all. I only get links to some folders and Server Configuration Manager. Where is that stupid client?!

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/ssms-2017-now-available-download/